# Проектирование базы данных. Как хранить табличные данные с неизвестным кол-вом столбцов?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Разрабатываю базу данных, в которой будут храниться прайс-листы для товаров. У каждого товара может быть несколько подчинённых прайс-листов. Цена будет формироваться в зависимости от количества и одной характеристики товара (параметра). Причём заранее неизвестно, какие будут у товара количества, и какие параметры.

```
TOVAR-1

┌───────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐    ┌───────────┬────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ subprice1 │ парам1 │ парам2 │  ...  │    │ subprice2 │ парам1 │ парам2 │  ...  │
├───────────┼────────┼────────┼───────┤    ├───────────┼────────┼────────┼───────┤
│ кол-во    │        │        │       │    │ кол-во    │        │        │       │
├───────────┼────────┼────────┼───────┤    ├───────────┼────────┼────────┼───────┤
│  ...      │        │        │       │    │  ...      │        │        │       │
└───────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘    └───────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Сделал две таблицы (связаны по полю `values.quantID = quantities.ID`):

`**quantities**  ID | tovarID | subprice  | quant`

`**values**      ID | quantID | paramName | value`

В принципе, все работает нормально. Но после того, как я внес в БД всего 13 товаров, в таблице `**values**` уже около 18000 записей, и размер таблицы 1.5 Мб. Не допустил ли я ошибку при проектировании? Если нет, то для каких полей нужно включить индексацию, чтоб со временем выборка не превратилась в кошмар?

Comment: Мне кажется вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией

Comment: @php5engineer не хочется еще раз всё переделывать, это уже 4я или 5я версия, переписанная почти с нуля :)

Comment: То, что Вы хотите получить называется [entity-attribute-value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). ИМХО использовать такой подход с реляционными БД имеет мало смысла. При таком подходе Вы не сможете нормально использовать ни `check constraint`, ни `foreig key` ни писать нормальные запросы. Различные внутренние оптимизации в реляционных БД при таком подходе тоже не будут работать. Если Вам нужно просто какое-то хранилище данных (которое совсем не реляционное) попробуйте посмотреть какие-нибудь другие варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно почитать хотя бы про нормальные формы. То что вы хотите исполнить совершенно испортит вам дальнейшую работу с этой базой. Приведите ваши таблицы к третьей нормальной форме. Выделите параметры в отдельную справочную таблицу, и храните отношения параметров и значений в таблице со структурой  Param-Value

```
Params             Goods             ParamsOfGoods
| ID | Name  |    | ID | Name  |     | ID | Goods | Param | Value |
|----|-------|    |----|-------|     |----|-------|-------|-------|  
| 1  | Param1|    | 1  | Water |     | 1  | 1     |   1   |   1   |
| 2  | Param1|    | 2  | Apple |     | 2  | 2     |   2   |   1   |
| 3  | Param2|    | 3  | Juice |     | 3  | 3     |   1   |   1   |
                                     | 4  | 1     |   2   |   3   |
```

Если необходимо хранить значения параметров разного типа, то храните всё в строках и создай дополнительную справочную таблицу с типами, добавь дополнительную колонку в справочник параметров.

```
Types
| ID | Name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | int   |
| 2  | string|
| 3  | refID |
Params                     Goods             ParamsOfGoods
| ID | Name  | Type  |    | ID | Name  |     | ID | Goods | Param | Value |
|----|-------|-------|    |----|-------|     |----|-------|-------|-------|  
| 1  | Param1| 1     |    | 1  | Water |     | 1  |   1   |   1   |   1   |
| 2  | Param1| 2     |    | 2  | Apple |     | 2  |   2   |   2   |   1   |
| 3  | Param2| 3     |    | 3  | Juice |     | 3  |   3   |   3   | 001egh|
                                             | 4  |   4   |   2   |   3   |
```

Тогда таблица цен примет вид. И будет содержать стоимость за единицу с определенной характеристикой.

```
Prices
| ID | ParamofGoods | Сost |
|----|--------------|------|
| 1  |       1      | 10   |
| 2  |       2      | 14   |
| 3  |       3      | 5    |
| 4  |       4      | 3    |
```

Так же в целях масштабируемости можно предположить что у товара может быть больше одной характеристики одновременно, например вкус и цвет. Тогда необходимо создать отдельные таблицы для записи в них всех возможных характеристик товара 
и выбирать в дальнейшем уже товары с комбинацией характеристик.

Comment: спасибо, наглядно. получилось взглянуть на всё это дело под другим углом. разбил на 4 маленьких талбицы (`Goods`, `Subprice`, `Quant`, `Param`). И в пятой собрал ссылки на эти таблицы и привязал к цене. `id | goodsid | subid | quantid | paramid | value`. Это конечно не сэкономит строк (всё равно одна цена - одна строка), но существенно упростит выборку.

Comment: @toxxxa, экономить строки не нужно, если данных много то от этого никуда не денешься. В данном случае важна простота и скорость выборки. И в дальнейшем, в целях оптимизации, при больших объемах данных возможно придется совершенно переделать структуру таблиц с ценами, для увеличения скорости формирования отчетов или других целей.

Answer (score 3):

Всегда можно завернуть широкую таблицу на  90 градусов, заведя таблицу

```
ID ID_товара ID_параметра Значение_параметра
```

Тогда у вас будет дополнительная таблица справочник

```
ID_параметра Описание_параметра
```

Это, по крайней мере, оставит базу реляционной.

Answer (score 1):

В нормальной практике динамическое количество столбцов никогда не делается (да и архитектура реляционных баз этого не позволяет).

Если это действительно надо, то в некоторых базах есть спец. типы данных что-то вроде JSONData, XMLData, которые позволяют в одном столбце хранить данные в соответсвующих форматах и потом средствами некоторого расширенного SQL синтаксиса запрашивать поля вложенных объектов, как обычные столбцы.

Но, насколько мне известно, в MySQL подобного рода возможностей нет (хотя вам конечно никто не мешает просто создать текстовое поле). И плюс данный функционал обычно используется в несколько нетипичных задачах.

Так что не рекомендую пока заниматься попытками такого рода "оптимизаций", как динамические столбцы.

Answer (score 1):

Как я бы это делал. Первая таблица - таблица с товаром и теми свойствами, которые гарантированно будут и важны. К примеру, цена, размеры, вес. Вторая таблица - это список возможных свойств. Также в этой таблице могут быть описания этих свойств, размерность (но тут можно уже и в дополнительную вынести:) ). И третья таблица - таблица привязки свойств. В ней будут такие поля - id товара, id свойства, значение свойства.

У этой методики есть только один недостаток - свойства должны быть одного типа. И обойти это можно несколькими способами.

- завести несколько таблиц - одну для строковых параметров, одну для числовых. плюсы - легко делать выборку, минус - данные размазываются
- хранить все в строках. Просто, легко. Для своих классов можно написать сериализатор/десириализатор и все будет прозрачно. Но если нужно выбрать товар по каких то критериям - это может быть очень накладно.
- хранить все в блобах. По сути, способ мало отличается от предыдущего, да и вручную просматривать данные сложнее, но зато компактнее.

И на самый конец - радикальные методы. Возможно, Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону MongoDB или Postgres.

MongoDB позволяет сохранять прямо json и делать выборки. И не нужно привязываться к списку полей.
А вот Postgres решил эту [проблему радикально](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html). Они позволяют создавать поля, в которых можно хранить json и потом можно делать выборки к полям этого json.